# Imports suddenly not working anymore - no module named xy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a project structure like this:

```
/adapters/adapter.py
/blockchain.py
/venv

#adapter.py  
from blockchain import Blockchain
class Adapter():
    pass

#blockchain.py
class Blockchain():
    pass
```

contains `from blockchain import Blockchain`
blockchain.py would is like `class Blockchain(): pass`

Now from adapter.py I want to import the class Blockchain which is located in blockchain.py

I am using python 3.6.6 (using venv) and I never had any problems doing that until today when I moved some stuff with **init** files into the project. I deleted all the files and pulled from the repo to make sure its exactly like before when it was working but I am getting

> no module named "blockchain"

I don't have any init files in my project and it worked for 2 weeks without a problem which is very strange. I know there are a lot of similar posts already, most of them suggesting to use **init** files, but I am very confused why it worked before and but anymore.

My sys.path is like this (bcios-master is the root folder):

> ['',
>   '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip',
>   '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6',
>   '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
>   '/Users/timo/Documents/bcio-master/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']

Somehow if I try to append it doesn't save it.

Comment: We need to see the full code of what you're trying to do, which I assume is just the `import` section near the top?

Comment: Append your base directory to your python path with `sys.path.append` - you'll be able to do `import blockchain` after that.

Comment: Is there a file named `__init__.py` in the directory of the file `blockchain.py`?

Comment: Show us the contents of `sys.path` inside of your program, please.  and show us the `class Blockchain()` line from `blockchain.py`, please.

Comment: thx for the responses, I added the infos you asked for

Comment: @SvenKrüger no, no init files, but it worked before without any so I hope I can avoid them

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path

Comment: @Pitto i can do `import sys sys.path.append('/Users/timo/Documents/bcio-master')` and then it works but then I would need this in every file. Seems strange that it worked before without it...

Comment: So my conclusion until now is that somehow it automatically set the pythonpath to my project root when I created the folder or venv. And apparently now its not there anymore